# Rattle at some point of clutch engagment when the pedal is coming up

Tags: clutch, rattle, pedals

I can hear rattling noise when I am releasing the clutch pedal. The problem is as follows. I push the clutch pedal to the end, change to the first gear, and start releasing the pedal (without pushing on the acceleration pedal for this test). At some point before the full engagement I can hear strong rattling noise from my car until the clutch pedal is fully up (at this point there is a little to no rattling noise). The point is that even if I push on the acceleration pedal, and at the same time release the clutch pedal faster to the full engagement point, I can still encounter this rattling effect (although not as strong as before) somewhere before the clutch pedal is fully up. This also happens for shifting to the second gear, but not for upper gears nor for the reverse gear. Is this normal?

2011 BMW 116d

Comment: From your description,  it seems likely a throw out bearing, but I'm not sure how the BMW clutch system is put together. If it's a dual mass configuration, it could be the flywheel assembly.

Comment: @Paul: It is a Dual Mass Flywheel system.

Comment: Do you only hear a rattle and not feel anything? I am also thinking it could be a transmission mount. I would open the hood of the vehicle and have someone accelerate from a stop without using the throttle and try to find where the noise is coming from

Comment: @method: I can feel that something in the engine compartment is shaking when this happens. This only happens when the speed of the car (and the engine rev) is very low. If I push the acceleration pedal more to increase the engine rev. to above 1000 rpm, then when I am releasing the clutch pedal, I almost don't hear (neither feel) any rattling noise.

Comment: Yes when you are revving higher the engine becomes more "balanced", specially if you are leasing the clutch and the engine rpms drop low it would shake more the lower the rpm. I would try to locate the mount and ask someone to take a look at how it shakes when you are starting from a stop

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar noise and it still persists but very minimal.
Because my Dominor 400 has slipper clutch the mechanics said its quite normal.
But im not convinced and did a chain adjustment along with clutch free play adjustment myself and the noise has reduced to over 90% of what it used to be.
It took about 20 to 30 minutes to get the right setting and few trial rides after each of the adjustment, which is a painstaking job and hence mechanics dont take much care about our problem... After its our bike and we need it to perform the way we want....Try out the adjustments and i am sure you will find the noise vanish or reduce to great extent....All the best... happy motoring... Wear Helmet and be Safe on roads...God bless